# Window.history browser back doesn't load page - jQuery - HTML5

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, browser-history

I am creating a slideshow which is changing images with jQuery. When i change the image i also change page title and page url without reloading the page. I am changing url with:

```
window.history.pushState({path:url},'',curentImage[3]);
rightNav.click( function(){
    imageArea.append(curentImage[2]);
    title.text(curentImage[4]);
    window.history.pushState({path:url},'',curentImage[3]);
});
```

If i click back on browser it changes the url to previous one, but doesn't load that page. How can i load page with previous url when i click browser back button?

Answer (score 0):

I have just figured out the solution that helps in my case. I have added event listener for popstate which is redirecting me to the url i wan, some default url, or can be set to previous url.

```
window.addEventListener("popstate", function(e) {
        window.location.href = defUrl;
});
```